# Decouple mouse & keyboard focus

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, autohotkey, evernote

I use windows 11, say i have two applications opened (for example browser that has video playing in it & notepad++), and each of the applications is displayed in separate monitor (i use dual monitors), so on one monitor I'm watching a video inside browser, and on another monitor I'm writing in notepad++ (taking notes from the video I'm watching) .

is there a way to have mouse focus kept in on the browser (so i could use mouse shortcuts to pause/resume/fast-forward/rewind the video) while maintaining keyboard focus on the notepad++ (so i can continue writing in notepad++ without the need to keep moving the cursor back to notepad++).

I think this can only be achieved by disabling cursor focus, that is keyboard focus following wherever my cursor clicks.

Not applicable, there is no such feature

Comment: You could quite easily change focus always after you're done with whatever mouse action. Either manually or programmatically. But don't look into trying to "decouple" their focus, because that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this AutoHotkey script:

```
; Activate Notepad++ after using the mouse on Microsoft​ Edge or Chrome:

#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#If WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") AND WinExist("ahk_class Notepad++")

    ~LButton Up::
    ~RButton Up::
    ~WheelUp::
    ~WheelDown::
        WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad++    
    return

#If

; Press F1 to disable or reenable the above hotkeys
F1:: Suspend

; Press Esc to terminate the script
Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: this worked perfectly fine! thank you very much for the help.
One more question though, what if i want keyboard focus to be on another program such as Mobaxterm SSH terminal? i tried replacing "Notepad++" with "Mobaxterm" in the script but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: The path to mobaxterm is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe

Comment: Replace `ahk_class Notepad++` with the exact title of that program window or with `ahk_exe MobaXterm.exe` .

Comment: Right click the tray icon of the script and click `Window Spy`. In that tool you can see and copy the exact title, the ahk_class and ahk_exe of the active window.

Comment: Sorry my bad, worked well with "ahk_exe MobaXterm.exe".
THANK YOU very much for this, really helped me saving tons and tons of hours!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't achieve that, and even if there's one, it should also be tedious when you try to  re-couple them.

A solid workaround is `Alt` + `Tab`. Since you have 2 applications, a simple `Alt` + `Tab` can help you switch focus between them.